# Trouble with assigning colored categories on a broken bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why am I getting such extended final colors (green) parts to these bars?

Each GUI box should take two comma-separated integers for start and duration of that category. The numbers should get a little larger for each category, so that the colors don't overlap.   This can be entered in all the rows of the GUI, one pair of numbers in each box:  1,9 10,19 20,29 30,39 40,49. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import tkinter as tk

# Define the data as a dictionary
data = {
    'x_values': [],
    'y_values': [(6.0, 2), (8.5, 2), (12.5, 2), (15.0, 2), (19.0, 2)]
}

# Define a list of colors and categories for the bars
colors = ('tab:red', 'tab:orange', 'tab:purple', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green')
categories = ('Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4', 'Cat5')
jobs = ('Job1', 'Job2', 'Job3', 'Job4', 'Job5')

# Create a GUI interface to get user input for x_values
def get_x_values():
    global data
    x_values = []
    for i in range(len(jobs)):
        values_list = []
        for j in range(len(categories)): 
            x, y = x_values_entry[i][j].get().split(',')
            values_list.append((int(x), int(y)))
        x_values.append(values_list)
    data['x_values'] = x_values
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

# Create a grid of input boxes for the x_values
x_values_entry = []
for i in range(len(jobs)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(categories)):
        if i == 0:
            label = tk.Label(root, text=categories[j])
            label.grid(row=i, column=j+1)
        if j == 0:
            label = tk.Label(root, text=jobs[i])
            label.grid(row=i+1, column=j)
        entry = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
        entry.grid(row=i+1, column=j+1)
        row.append(entry)
    x_values_entry.append(row)

# Add a button to submit the x_values and close the GUI
submit_button = tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=get_x_values)
submit_button.grid(row=len(jobs)+1, columnspan=len(categories)+1)

# Run the GUI
root.mainloop()

# Define a list of colors and categories for the bars
colors = ('tab:red', 'tab:orange', 'tab:purple', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green')
categories = ('Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4', 'Category 5')

# Add the colors and categories to each row of the DataFrame
for i in range(len(data['x_values'])):
    data['facecolors'] = [colors] * len(data['x_values'])
    data['categories'] = [categories] * len(data['x_values'])

# Create a pandas DataFrame from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a new figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

# Loop through each row of the DataFrame and plot the broken bar chart
for i, row in df.iterrows():                             #makes no dif 0 or i here^
    ax.broken_barh(row['x_values'], row['y_values'], facecolors=row['facecolors'])
    #ax.broken_barh(row['x_values'], row['y_values'], facecolors=row['facecolors'])

# Create legend entries with color rectangles and category labels
legend_entries = [Patch(facecolor=color, edgecolor='black', label=category) for color, category in zip(colors, categories)]

# Add the legend to the plot
ax.legend(handles=legend_entries, loc='upper right', ncol=5, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.00))

# Customize the axis labels and limits
ax.set_xlabel('Days')
ax.set_ylabel('Jobs')
ax.set_yticks([7, 9.5, 13.5, 16, 20], labels=['Job1', 'Job2', 'Job3','Job4', 'Job5'])
                                                    
                                                  
title = ax.set_title('Tasks and Crew-Days')
title.set_position([0.5, 1.0])               #set title at center
ax.set_ylim(5, 26)
ax.grid(True)

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'def get_x_values' needs to be replaced with this code in order to eliminate any reading of whitespace from the GUI input values.  The code works fine for me with this slight change to the split() line:

```
# Create a GUI interface to get user input for x_values
def get_x_values():
    global data
    x_values = []
    for i in range(len(jobs)):
        values_list = []
        for j in range(len(categories)): 
            x, y = x_values_entry[i][j].get().replace(' ', '').split(',')
            values_list.append((int(x),int(y)))
        x_values.append(values_list)
    data['x_values'] = x_values
    print(x_values)
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
```